# css navigationbar: sub sub menu overlaps main menu in IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navigationbar

the following navigation bar works perfect on firefox, IE and Chrome. However, on IE, the sub sub menu that displays when a sub menu is clicked is not correctly positioned. It seems to overlap the main menu.

HOw can I position it correctly for IE without affecting the navigation bar layout in other browsers? The problem is on the last line of navbar.css code. Margin-top:-23px works perfect in all browsers except IE. I'm facing the problem on hover:

1. News and Events (the Sports Day LInk and Annual Day link are overlapping FAQ(main menu item)
2. Admissions (Enroll Now link overlaps Admissions link itself)

By the way, i'm testing on IE9.

Thank you.

navbar.css

```
#menu {
border:none;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
margin-bottom:5%;
padding:0px;
    /*font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#nav {
    height:25px;    /*35px;*/
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ffcd05;
        }

#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
/*    background: #006633;
*/  background:#f26739;

    }

#nav li a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:126px;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    }

#nav li li {float:left; #006633;}

#nav li li a {display:block;font-size:14px;}

#nav li:hover {background:#000000;}

/*--- Sublist Styles ---*/
#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0px;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    }

/*--- Hide Sub Sublists ---*/
#nav li:hover ul ul {display:none;}

/*--- Sublevel UL's display and position on hover ---*/
#nav li:hover ul {display:block;} 
#nav li li:hover ul {margin-left:110px; margin-top:-23px; display:block;}
```

My navigation bar:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
<!--        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/pages/home', array()); ?></li>
-->         <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Our Program', '#', array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Preschool', '/pages/preschool', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Kindergarten', '/pages/kindergarten', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Summer Camp', '/pages/summer_camp', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('About Us','#', array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Merry Flowers', '/pages/about_us', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Tour Our School','/pages/tour_our_school', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Contact Us', '/pages/contact_us', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('My Child','#', array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Report Card', '/merry_parents/register', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Events','#', array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php  echo $this->Html->link('News & Events', '#', array()); ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Sports Day','/pages/sports_day',array()); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Annual Day','/pages/annual_day',array()); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><?php  echo $this->Html->link('List of Holidays', '/pages/list_of_holidays', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('FAQ','#',array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php  echo $this->Html->link('FAQ', '/pages/faq', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php  echo $this->Html->link('Feedback', '/feedbacks/add', array()); ?></li>
            <li><?php  echo $this->Html->link('Discussion', '/forum/home', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Admissions','#',array()); ?><ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Enroll Now','/students/add', array()); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!--finish ul nav-->
</div> <!--finish div menu-->
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: ok, i'm trying to create a simplified version and i get back soon.

Comment: Please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/vaanipala/yvRG6/. I want to know how to adjust the positioning for Sports Day, Annual Day and Enrol Now sub links.

Comment: In the simplified version in jsfiddle it appears fine but when it comes to the real thing like the above, the sublinks are overlapping the main menu items.

Comment: Which makes me wonder if you are using a doctype. Having problems with IE is normal and expected.

Comment: Or, something in the added fancy bits for your real version is messing with it. What did you remove?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it working. Once I added top:23px for the sublists style, sports day and annual day submenus did not overlap news and events. Thanks you.

```
#menu {
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:none;
margin-bottom:5%;


 /*font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#nav{
  padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  float:left;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#ffcd05;
}

#nav li{ /*our program, about us, my child, event, etc..*/
     float:left;
     display:block;
     text-align:center;
     background:#f26739;
      width:126px;
      position:relative;  /*very important for good layout of submenus*/
     }
#nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li ul li{font-size:14px;}

#nav li:hover{
      background:#000000;
}
/* sublists style */
#nav ul{  /*lists that come under our program, event, etc...*/
position:absolute; /* very impt for good layout of submenus*/
left:0px;
top:23px;  /*sports day and annual day submenus will not overlap news and events*/
display:none;
padding:0;
}

/*--- Hide Sub Sublists ---*/
#nav li:hover ul ul {display:none;}

/*--- Sublevel UL's display and position on hover ---*/
#nav li:hover ul{display:block;}

#nav li li:hover ul {margin-left:110px; margin-top:-23px;display:block;}
```